# How to fix "undefined reference to symbol 'vxCannyEdgeDetectorNode'" error compiling openvx on yocto

Tags: opencv, yocto, openvx

I'm trying to compile the OpenCV version 4.1.0 whith OpenVX enabled on yocto but It is raising an "undefined referece" error. I already try to include the the "lm" library as a dependency, but I think that It is not available to Yocto. I also noticed that the VX/vx.h file was not present on the OpenCV or OpenVX sources. Does someone have some idea of how I can resolve this error?

```
CMakeFiles/example_openvx_no_wrappers.dir/no_wrappers.cpp.o: undefined reference to symbol 'vxCannyEdgeDetectorNode'
~/imx-yocto-bsp/build/tmp/sysroots/apalis-imx8/usr/lib/libOpenVX.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/example_openvx_no_wrappers] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `~/imx-yocto-bsp/build/tmp/work/aarch64-mx8qm-poky-linux/opencv/4.1.0+gitAUTOINC+371bba8f54_2c32791a9c_32e315a5b1_34e4206aef_fccf7cd6a4-r0/build'
make[1]: ***[samples/openvx/CMakeFiles/example_openvx_no_wrappers.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

In my opencv_4.1.0.bbappend I put the following PACKAGECONFIG:

```
PACKAGECONFIG[openvx] = " \
    -DWITH_OPENVX=ON -DOPENVX_ROOT=${STAGING_LIBDIR} -DOPENVX_LIB_CANDIDATES='OpenVX;OpenVXU', \
    -DWITH_OPENVX=OFF, \
    virtual/libopenvx, \
    \
"
```